# how to use puppeteer $$eval

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Is there a way to run a click event by getting only the list you want from the list?

I want to 'const value = "li elements that meet the requirements";

that requirements is "e.getAttribute('date')) > 20220406 && Number(e.getAttribute('date')) < 20220408"

```js
let bc = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();

  let page = await browser.newPage();
  
  //... omission
  
const value = await list_date.filter(async(element)=>{
      return await frame.evaluate((e)=>{
        return Number(e.getAttribute('date')) > 20220406 && Number(e.getAttribute('date')) < 20220408
      },element)
    })
```

```html
<ul class="content scroll-y" tabindex="-1" style="right: -15px;"><div><li class="month dimmed"><div><span class="year">2022</span><span class="month">4</span><div></div></div></li><li data-index="0" date="20220404" class="day today selected"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="dayweek">월</span><span class="day">4</span><span class="sreader">선택됨</span></a><span class="today"></span></li><li data-index="1" date="20220405" class="day"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="dayweek">화</span><span class="day">5</span><span class="sreader"></span></a></li><li data-index="2" date="20220406" class="day"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="dayweek">수</span><span class="day">6</span><span class="sreader"></span></a></li><li data-index="3" date="20220407" class="day"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="dayweek">목</span><span class="day">7</span><span class="sreader"></span></a></li><li data-index="4" date="20220408" class="day"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="dayweek">금</span><span class="day">8</span><span class="sreader"></span></a></li><li data-index="5" date="20220409" class="day day-sat"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="dayweek">토</span><span class="day">9</span><span class="sreader"></span></a></li><li data-index="6" date="20220410" class="day day-sun"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="dayweek">일</span><span class="day">10</span><span class="sreader"></span></a></li><li data-index="7" date="20220411" class="day dimmed"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="dayweek">월</span><span class="day">11</span><span class="sreader">선택불가</span></a></li><li data-index="8" date="20220412" class="day dimmed"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="dayweek">화</span><span class="day">12</span><span class="sreader">선택불가</span></a></li><li data-index="9" date="20220413" class="day dimmed"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="dayweek">수</span><span class="day">13</span><span class="sreader">선택불가</span></a></li><li data-index="10" date="20220416" class="day day-sat dimmed"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="dayweek">토</span><span class="day">16</span><span class="sreader">선택불가</span></a></li><li data-index="11" date="20220417" class="day day-sun dimmed"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="dayweek">일</span><span class="day">17</span><span class="sreader">선택불가</span></a></li><li data-index="12" date="20220419" class="day dimmed"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="dayweek">화</span><span class="day">19</span><span class="sreader">선택불가</span></a></li><li data-index="13" date="20220424" class="day day-sun dimmed"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="dayweek">일</span><span class="day">24</span><span class="sreader">선택불가</span></a></li><li data-index="14" date="20220426" class="day dimmed"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="dayweek">화</span><span class="day">26</span><span class="sreader">선택불가</span></a></li><li data-index="15" date="20220430" class="day day-sat dimmed"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="dayweek">토</span><span class="day">30</span><span class="sreader">선택불가</span></a></li></div></ul>
```

Comment: filter is not an async function and its callbacks should also not be async.

Comment: What is `list_date`? What does "getting only the list you want from the list" mean? Please share a [mcve] and clearly state your expected output requirements.

Comment: @ggorlen I added some requirements and contents.